# How does spriteBatch.DrawString draw text from compiled spritesheet texture?

Tags: c#, xna, drawstring, spritebatch

Does each `spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, "text", new Vector2(10, 20), Color.White)` call draw every letter of the text string separately (calls `spriteBatch.Draw` for each letter each frame), or does it make one texture and redraws it, or does it work in some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It internally calls SpriteBatch.Draw() for each letter. then when you call SpriteBatch.End(), it hands the whole batch and any other Texture2D sprites you may have drawn 
since calling .Begin() to the GPU for rendering.